# Regex to highlight invalid tokens

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Hi have a field were the user can enter a string with a limited set of tokens, say `{token1}`, `{token2}`. Token is a string between curly braces, no spaces allowed.

I want to have the entry of the user checked with regex to invalidate when the user enters any unknown/invalid token. Note that the user can as well not enter a token at all.

Valid entries:

- `qwert yuiop`
- `qwert{token1}yuiop`
- `qwert{token1}{token2}yuiop`
- `qwert {token1} {token2} yuiop`

Invalid entries:

- `qwert {badtoken} yuiop`
- `qwert { badtoken} yuiop`
- `qwert {badtoken } yuiop`
- `qwert { token1} yuiop`
- `qwert {token1 } yuiop`
- `qwert { token1 } yuiop`
- `qwert {badtoken} {token1} yuiop`

Intention-wise, the message to the user will say:

> The entry contains unknown tokens. Only {token1} and {token2} are allowed.

Comment: What language are you using, JS? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
\{(?!token[12]\}).*?\}
```

The part that most people don't think of in cases like this is including the ending brace (`\}`) in the negative lookahead, to prevent matching things like `{token1 }` or `{token2xxxx}`.

Of course, this doesn't detect tokens with missing braces, like `{token1` or `token2}`.  That would be a lot more complicated.

This regex will work in any flavor that supports lookaheads and reluctant quantifiers.  Here's a **[demo](https://regex101.com/r/aE6fV4/1)**.

**Update:** Per the request in a comment, here's a spelled-out version (as you would use for token names that can't be easily condensed):

```
\{(?!(?:token1|token2)\}).*?\}
```

...and an updated **[demo](https://regex101.com/r/aE6fV4/2)**.

Comment: Alan can you give me the regex with the tokens spelled out please. I'll test this shortly.

Comment: Alan one more thing, I'm missing something. I need to use this with IsMatch, and it should go as the following:  
- no tokens or all valid tokens, IsMatch should return true,  
- bad tokens, IsMatch should return false  
  
Reason being I'm using this for validation on a cms system, which apparently expects bool results.

Comment: You probably should have said that up front.  You'll need to match *valid* tokens, while making sure the rest of the string contains no illegal characters (whatever those are).  In other words, it's almost exactly the opposite of what we've been working on.  If you need help with that, you should post another question.

Comment: You are right. I have decided to use this regex because it gives me the best off both worlds. I only have to make a custom implementation of the validator that will be consuming this to interpret match as negative.